# System.IO.FileNotFoundException with DocumentFormat.OpenXml v 2.16.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, revit-api

**Context of solution**: Currently, I have an external application called `kdsRibbon` which creates and facilitates a ribbon in Revit called "KDS TOOLS". Within this ribbon, there are multiple panels and buttons. I use the `.InvokeMember` property to link each button with an external command that is in a separate solution. By using `InvokeMember`, the ribbon looks into a specified file location to find the .dll of the external command and runs the Execute class of the external command. This also allows for rapid iteration of the external commands without restarting Revit each time.

One of the external commands I have linked to my Ribbon is called ExportXLTM (button name is Export/Import Excel), where I want to export specified data into an excel sheet with a .xltm extension. The only issue is, to do this, I need to use the reference `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` for properties to allow exportation to excel. I install `DocumentFormat.OpenXML` through Nuget, and I am able to build  my solution successfully, but whenever I debug I receive this error:

> **"System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.16.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fb06cb64d019a17' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'"**

So, to my understanding the flow is kdsRibbon --> Invoke External Command --> External Command runs --> Relies on DocumentFormat.OpenXml --> Error

I have looked up this error countless times and tried many things. I have changed copy local property to true, I have ensured that `DocumentFormat.OpenXML` and `WindowsBase` are both available to the solution, I have tried having both .dll files in Reference Assemblies folder, having them in the same folder location as the kdsRibbon.dll and the ExportXLTM.dll (these are in the same location folder), and I have put both .dll files in the bin of the ExportXLTM solution, and all of these return the same error. I ensured that `System.IO` is correctly referenced in both my Ribbon and External Command and I still receive the same error.

Is there something I am missing or can anyone help me towards a solution? Does it have to do with the Invoke Member property that causes visual studios to look in the wrong directory location for the .dll files? I have exhausted my possible solutions and I am stuck.

UPDATE: Since I am new I am not allowed to embed images so I have attached links

[kdsRibbon with panels and buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFDgx.png)

[Error Message in Debug mode within ExportXLTM external command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzW1B.png)

[InvokeMember usage within kdsRibbon External Application, references external command, and also where error occurs within kdsRibbon (highlighted area)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4K4qg.png)

Comment: Please do not include images of your code. Add the code directly to the post. See [How do I ask a  good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -1):

You likely have another addin installed that uses a different version of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.